# how to install jpcap-0.7 completely

Tags: java

I need to install jpcap-0.7 software but, every time I try to install using the jpcap-0.7.deb file, I get an error saying: `dependency is not satisfiable : sun-java6.jdk` ,while oracle-java6 is already installed in my system.

So how can I install jpcap-0.7 ?

Answer (score 1):

The latest release for jpcap was in 2011, so the `jpcap-0.7.deb` file will be wildly outdated relative to current Ubuntu - or in fact to any still supported release of Ubuntu.

Use installation from source, as described on the jpcap site, or look for an up-to-date successor for the software.  Ubuntu comes with several excellent package inspectors.